# How can I make the bot write on how many servers it is active in its status? (Discord.py Rewrite)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

What I want to do is actually the bot to write both my messages and how many servers are online.

My Code:

```
status = cycle([f"I am online on {len(bot.guilds)} servers!","Second Status")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")
    await change_status.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds = 30)
async def change_status():
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(next(status)))
```

When I try that, Bot status is as follows:

> I am online on 0 servers!

and every time the loop repeats, the bot says:

> I am online on 0 servers!

But the bot is currently online on 3 servers. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define status in the function, so it's constantly updating and loads after the bot is ready.

```py
status = 0

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")
    await change_status.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds = 30)
async def change_status():
    statuses = [f"I am online on {len(bot.guilds)} servers!", "Second Status"]
    if status + 1 > len(statuses):
        status = 0
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(statuses[status]))
    status += 1
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I put the statuses into the function it restarts the list at the beginning of each loop so I can only see the 1st status.

Comment: Try now, I've never used cycle so I've made my code use pure python, it simply goes through the list by indexing a certain integer.